# What does importing a subdirectory mean in Python 3.4?

Tags: python-3.x, package

I thought a package should always contain `__init__.py` file. But this seems to work for me.

```
C:\Windows>python
Python 3.4.0b3 (v3.4.0b3:a97ce3ecc96a, Jan 26 2014, 17:50:55) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import System32
>>>
```

How did `import System32` succeed even though I did not have any **init**.py file in it?

It looks like I can import packages from subdirectories as well and use it as if the subdirectory was a valid Python package.

```
C:\Windows>echo def bar(): print('hi') > System32\foo.py

C:\Windows>python
Python 3.4.0b3 (v3.4.0b3:a97ce3ecc96a, Jan 26 2014, 17:50:55) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import System32.foo
>>> System32.foo.bar()
hi
```

Can you please help me understand why subdirectories behave like packages even without `__init__.py`? Quotes from the official documentation would be great!

Comment: Can I ask why you are working out of `System32` and apparently with Administrator rights?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I am not working out of `System32`. I executed a few commands there only to demonstrate the `import` behaviour I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I conducted some research to find out what the reason to this strange behaviour was. My research revealed three things:

1. It works cross platform. I'm on linux, you're on windows.
2. It does not work in python 2.7
3. Packages without `__init__.py` files are loaded by `_frozen_importlib.NamespaceLoader`

This revealed that this behaviour had something to do with namespaces. After some googling I found the documentation of it:

> Namespace packages
>
> A namespace package is a composite of various portions, where each portion contributes a subpackage to the parent package. Portions may reside in different locations on the file system. Portions may also be found in zip files, on the network, or anywhere else that Python searches during import. Namespace packages may or may not correspond directly to objects on the file system; they may be virtual modules that have no concrete representation.
>
> Namespace packages do not use an ordinary list for their **path** attribute. They instead use a custom iterable type which will automatically perform a new search for package portions on the next import attempt within that package if the path of their parent package (or sys.path for a top level package) changes.
>
> With namespace packages, there is no parent/**init**.py file. In fact, there may be multiple parent directories found during import search, where each one is provided by a different portion. Thus parent/one may not be physically located next to parent/two. In this case, Python will create a namespace package for the top-level parent package whenever it or one of its subpackages is imported.

You can read it in the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/import.html?highlight=import#namespace-packages). There is also a [PEP here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of answer I was looking for.